# Can I use RVMs 'head' ruby in production?

Tags: ruby, rvm, production

I'm using RVM to install Ruby on production server. Listing the known rubies gives me

```
[ruby-]2.2.0
[ruby-]2.2-head
```

Is it safe to use `2.2-head` in production mode or better rely on `2.2.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use 2.2.0 in production. 
As it is stable.

Every month or two a stable release of RVM is created, it includes minor version increase. Between releases only bugfixes and ruby version updates are added to it with teeny version update. Normal development and major changes continue on master branch to install it use head version. It's important to use head version before reporting errors as those could be already fixed.